# How to create a global js variable initialized by my Rails app variable the right way?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my AppController I have a variable @current_user. I want to create a global namespaced variable in accross my all js files so
that it gets initialized when @current_user exists -- a user is loged in, that is. Also I want it to be namespaced so it won't rewrite or get rewritten by other js variables if there happen to be any with the same name.

How can I properly do that?

I think I should create a js variable in my base **layout**, at the very top:

```
<script>
var currentUser = {};
<% if @current_user %>
  currentUser = {id: <%= @current_user.id %>, email: '<%= @current_user.email %>'};
<% end %>
</script>
```

Is this a solid approach? Or is there a better one?

Also - how do I add a namespace to my js variable so that it'll become:

```
 MyApp.currentUser
```

?

Answer (score 1):

To have a better separation between the JavaScript and the Rails code, you could define a DOM element in your template, that element will contain the data you are passing to JavaScript. Then use JavaScript to get the data:

In your ERB template:

```
<%= content_tag :div, id:"js-user-data", data: {current_user_id: @current_user.id, current_user_email: @current_user.email} do %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your JavaScript code:

```
var user_id = $("#js-user-data").data('current_user_id');
var user_email = $("#js-user-data").data('current_user_email');
```

That way you won't be writing JavaScript with your ERB, just accessing data from a DOM element.

Comment: how is that better?